# In a Salesforce Number field, how much performance impact does its length have?

Tags: apex, dml, performance, number

Does a `2,2` field perform noticeably better than a `16,2` if the same value (e.g. `24.45`) is stored in the context of

1. Apex
2. DML
3. Formulas
4. whatever I forgot, please add

To clarify: This question assumes the manipulation of as many records as might be needed to actually perceive the impact. (Thx, Drew)

Comment: I'd think it would be quite negligible for one field, but if you were to do this a lot, you would start to notice performance degradation with the database. The general rule is to select lengths that make the most sense - no different for numbers than for text fields.

Comment: Thank you. I agree and edited the question to clarify. Also, I am interested in the specifics of the platform.

Answer (score 5):

The only things we need to concern ourselves with are writing optimal Apex Code and Visual Flows, and trust that the platform will provide the most optimal storage and performance that it can. The **only** time we care about using (2,2) instead of (16,2) is for Custom Settings, where each digit configured uses additional bytes in our limited Custom Settings storage space. Custom settings should **always** be configured to use exactly as many digits as necessary, and no more.

Aside from Custom Settings storage, all other number fields are stored in a standardized format, which supports at least 18 digits of accuracy on the left and right size of the decimal point. In Apex Code, this translates to a usage of 28 bytes of memory per number retrieved from the database, regardless if the number is 1.0, 12345678901234567.8, or any other type of value that can be stored in a Decimal.

During a DML operation, incoming values are translated to this same standardized format, regardless of the configured display values; in this way, a (2,2) number uses the same amount of space as a (16,2) number. Formulas always operate on the internal format and then round the final result to fit in the display format of the formula (e.g. if the formula returns 2 decimal places, it will be rounded as such).

Note that because the internal storage format is much larger than any value you can configure, this can cause some strange side effects if you load values of higher precision in the database than the display precision. For example, if you add an Opportunity Product to an Opportunity, and set the Quantity to 1.499, the displayed value for Quantity will be 1.50, but the Amount on the Opportunity will be set to (Unit Price * 1.499), which will lead to a visual discrepancy.

Unlike traditional databases, the size of the record "on disk" does not reflect the amount of data storage that we're "charged" with using. For example, an Account always uses 2KB of data storage, even if it has a Description that is several pages long (which would clearly use more than 2KB by itself). So, unlike MySQL, where fine-tuning the parameters would have a performance in terms of record size or other metrics, this setting has absolutely no effect on the performance of the Salesforce application.

You should always use the most appropriate number based on business needs instead of trying to tune for performance, because it's largely out of your hands anyways. Salesforce.com works hard to make sure that the database is operating at peak efficiency with minimal effort for developers, meaning we can focus on designing applications instead of worrying about platform nuances.

Comment: Awesome answer! I hesitate to accept it because I'd love to get some reference links. That being said: if from your experience there aren't any, I'll accept it nonetheless

Comment: > Unlike traditional databases, the size of the record "on disk" does not reflect the amount of data storage that we're "charged" with using.  -- See "Salesforce record size overview" https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383664&type=1 for one reference link